# C - Larger Output Than I have in File (Size Problem)

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I have a file, with format:

Course - Grade Count - Grades

```
Programming 10 3 4 5 4 3 2 4 5 2 3
Mathematics 8 3 3 4 5 3 2 2 3
Physics 6 3 4 5 3 4 5
Design 6 5 4 5 3 2 4
Logistics 8 3 4 5 3 1 1 2 4
```

Ex: Course - Programming, Grade Count - 10 and Grades - 3 4 5 4 3 2 4 5 2 3

I already have

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define SIZE 70

int main(void)
{
    char subject[SIZE];
    int gradeCount;
    int grades[SIZE];

    FILE *fp = fopen("C:\\Project\\project.txt", "r"); //opening already created file


    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return(-1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {

        fscanf(fp, "%s %d", &subject[i], &gradeCount);
        printf("%s \n", &subject[i]);
        //printf("%d \n", gradeCount);
        for (int k = 0; k < gradeCount; k++)
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &grades[k]);
            // printf("%d \n" , grades[k]);

        }

        if (i == SIZE) {
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

I need to print out "Course", "Grade Count" and "Grades" without any problems, later on I need to make a search and so I need to separate them from each other, but that is not the case, now I will show you the outputs for all cases, when I output first "Subject/Course" then "Grade Count" and finally "Grades".

For Courses:

```
Programming
Mathematics
Physics
Design
Logistics
ogistics
gistics
istics
stics
tics
ics
cs
s

@

@@
@
@
```

For Grade Count:

```
10
8
6
6
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
8
```

And for Grades:

```
3
4
5
4
3
2
4
5
2
3
3
3
4
5
3
2
2
3
3
4
5
3
4
5
5
4
5
3
2
4
3
4
5
3
1
1
2
4
3
4
5
3
1
1
2
4
3
4
5
3
1
1
2
4
3
4
5
3
1
1
2
4
3
4
5
3
1
1
2
4
3
4
5
3
1
1
2
4
3
4
5
3
1
1
2
4
3
4
5
3
1
1
2
4
3
4
5
3
1
1
2
4
3
4
5
3
1
1
2
4
3
4
5
3
1
1
2
4
3
4
5
3
1
1
2
4
3
4
5
3
1
1
2
4
3
4
5
3
1
1
2
4
3
4
5
3
1
1
2
4
3
4
5
3
1
1
2
4
```

In all cases, additional things are added to original stuff that should be printed out, I don't know where it comes from, I thought about pointers, but don't know much about them. Any suggestions?

Just need to print everything normally to normally search for everything (Courses, grade count and grades) later on.

Comment: Start by adding error checking to your code; especially with `fscanf()`.

Comment: Suspect you've mis-declared `subject` - it looks like you're expecting it to be an array of strings, but instead you've just got it as a string.

Comment: `if (i == SIZE)` in your loop will never happen because you only loop while `i < SIZE`. You have to think about a better way to exit the loop if there is no more input.

Comment: @ChrisTurner Array of chars and it should be a string, that is the idea.

Comment: A string is an array of `char`s. A array of strings is an array of arrays of `char`s.

Comment: @Swordfish What if I use EOF ?

Comment: In that case you're reading it in incorrectly, you just want to pass `subject` to `scanf` and `printf` not `&subject[i]`

Comment: You might want to look up which values `fscanf()` returns under which conditions.

Comment: @ChrisTurner Did that and It just leaves first letters. Programming PMathematics PMPhysics and like that and still adds more stuff at the end

Answer (score 0):

You need to exit the loop early if it fails to read anything in. You can do that by checking the return value of `fscanf`. If the first call doesn't return 2, you know that it didn't read in 2 values and can `break` out of the loop.

You're also calling `fscanf` and `printf` incorrectly for dealing with a string. You are moving the starting point of where you read into/print from, which isn't needed and reduces the maximum space available to you.

Updated code looks something like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    if(fscanf(fp, "%s %d", subject, &gradeCount) != 2) {
        break;
    }

    printf("%s ", subject);
    //printf("%d \n", gradeCount);
    for (int k = 0; k < gradeCount; k++)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &grades[k]);
        // printf("%d" , grades[k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I used it, but it outputs something mixed, it gives me all the subjects and it is good, but it mixes with grades, but incomplete and incorrect amount of grades, grade count should be just 1 number for each course

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - the code I've included should just print out each `subject`. It doesn't print out `gradeCount` or the `grades` as those lines are commented out.

Comment: I understand and that is the main reason of this question, it just acts strangely. This is the output I get.

Programming 3 5 3 4 2 Mathematics 3 4 3 2 Physics 3 5 4 Design 5 5 2 Logistics 3 5 1 2

Comment: If that's the output you're getting, then you're not running the code included in the question, with or without my changes. If I run that code I get just "Programming Mathematics Physics Design Logistics"